# How do I trim my SQL and still find records with duplicate data in two different fields?

Tags: mysql, sql

Basically, I'm trying to find all possible duplicates in a database based on phone numbers. My SQL is ugly and takes a long time because of all the SELECTs. How do I refine this and still get all possible duplicates?

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a3e2e/1)

**MySQL 5.5 Schema Setup**:

```
create table contacts (id int, name varchar(255), phone1 varchar(255), phone2 varchar (255));
insert into contacts (id, name, phone1, phone2) values(1, 'abe', 111, 122);
insert into contacts (id, name, phone1, phone2) values(2, 'abe', 111, 133);
insert into contacts (id, name, phone1, phone2) values(3, 'bob', 211, 222);
insert into contacts (id, name, phone1, phone2) values(4, 'carol', 233, 222);
insert into contacts (id, name, phone1, phone2) values(5, 'david', 311, 322);
insert into contacts (id, name, phone1, phone2) values(6, 'eve', 333, 311);
insert into contacts (id, name, phone1, phone2) values(7, 'fiona', 411, 422);
insert into contacts (id, name, phone1, phone2) values(8, 'gabe', 422, 433);
insert into contacts (id, name, phone1, phone2) values(9, 'harold', 511, 511);
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT id, name, phone1, phone2 FROM contacts
        WHERE (phone1 IN (SELECT phone1 FROM contacts GROUP BY phone1 HAVING count(phone1) > 1))
        OR (phone2 IN (SELECT phone2 FROM contacts GROUP BY phone2 HAVING count(phone2) > 1))
        OR (phone1 IN (SELECT phone2 FROM contacts))
        OR (phone2 IN (SELECT phone1 FROM contacts))
        ORDER BY phone1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a3e2e/1/0)**:
    | id |   name | phone1 | phone2 |
    |----|--------|--------|--------|
    |  1 |    abe |    111 |    122 |
    |  2 |    abe |    111 |    133 |
    |  3 |    bob |    211 |    222 |
    |  4 |  carol |    233 |    222 |
    |  5 |  david |    311 |    322 |
    |  6 |    eve |    333 |    311 |
    |  7 |  fiona |    411 |    422 |
    |  8 |   gabe |    422 |    433 |
    |  9 | harold |    511 |    511 |

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT c1.id, c1.name, c1.phone1, c1.phone2 
FROM contacts AS c1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT id, phone1, phone2
    FROM contacts
) AS c2 ON (c1.id <> c2.id AND (c1.phone1 = c2.phone1 OR c1.phone2 = c2.phone2))
GROUP BY c1.id
ORDER BY c1.phone1
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ad9ee/5

And put index on your (phone1) and (phone2):

```
ALTER TABLE `contacts` ADD INDEX (`phone1`);
ALTER TABLE `contacts` ADD INDEX (`phone2`);
```

Comment: Yes, that gets all the cases and it's very fast! Thank you so much! It's been 15 years since I've taken a database class. What do you mean, "put index on your (phone1) and (phone2)?" Do I need to add the c2 prefix to the fields in the inner join select?

Comment: actually, that didn't work, it also pulls unique phone1 or phone2 into the results

Comment: sorry.. but about "unicality" nothing in the question were. you said that u need reorganize your query and maybe speedup. and yes, it gives you all duplicates. what u mean? this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a3e2e/4 ? no sense.  please add more details

Comment: I really appreciate your help, M0rtiis. This http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ad9ee/3/0 should show that even the "ivan" contact is being pulled into the results even though his phones are not duplicates of any one else's phones. That's really the point - trying to find ALL the duplicates - no singular instances, with as few traversals as possible.

Comment: no, but it's fine. I appreciate you trying. I'll just have to dig up my database design books out of storage. I've looked elsewhere online and there just not doing it the same way of comparing one field in one record and comparing it against a different field in a different record and grabbing both records if they're the same - oh well, good luck!